# WPF border animation not working

Tags: wpf

I am trying to put an animation on a border as follows

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RedButtonBrushUp" StartPoint=".5,0" EndPoint=".5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#ffaaaa" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#cc6666" Offset="0.6"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#bb2222" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonBrushUp" StartPoint=".5,0" EndPoint=".5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#aaccff" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#7799ff" Offset="0.6"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#555599" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>


<Border x:Name="BorderUp" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Background="{StaticResource RedButtonBrushUp}">
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderUp"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                     AutoReverse="True"
                                     To="{StaticResource ButtonBrushUp}"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" ></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>
                </Border>
```

But it says {StaticResource ButtonBrushUp} is an invalid type for this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The To can't accept such a change needed for the gradient brush stops.

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="myBorder">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FFC53838"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded" SourceName="myBorder">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
 <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border x:Name="myBorder" Background="#99FFFFFF" BorderThickness="3"
    Margin="0,60,0,20" Padding="20"  >
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
      <TextBlock>
        This example shows how to have a border change color after an initial load.
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Just running my app now with some changes and the animation is running, but when the mouse is over the window it freezes, starts and stops sporadically and is very jerky and stops for a lot of the time. As soon as the mouse is no longer hovering over the application window and is on another area of the desktop, the animation resumes smoothly and executes normally. Why is this?

Comment: @user1122909 Run my test code in a seperate test project, for it doesn't happen in mine when I move the mouse anywhere within the screen.